# Terraform command line arguments doesn't work with conditional expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to deploy a resource block either into dev or prod depending on the variable using conditional expression , for this i am trying to use command line argument.
This work with terraform.tfvars but doesn't work with CMD arguments which means when i am trying to run `terraform plan` it doesn't not have any other changes.

ideally it should add 1 instance.

here is my resource block

main.tf file

```
resource "aws_instance" "dev" {

  ami           = "ami-0ca285d4c2cda3300"
  instance_type = var.instanceType
  count         = var.istest == true ? 1 : 0
}

resource "aws_instance" "prod" {

  ami           = "ami-0ca285d4c2cda3300"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  count         = var.istest == false ? 1 : 0
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "istest" {
  default = true
}
```

terraform .tf vars is empty, command to run terraform

```
terraform plan -var="istest=false"
```

Comment: "doesn't work with CMD arguments" what does it mean? Any errors? In other words, what is happening when you run your plan command?

Comment: There are no changes at all with terraform plan command. ideally it should add a instance.

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but you did not declare the type of your variable in variables.tf



https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#type-constraints



I think you want bool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use the following syntax instead of checking for the literal `true` or `false` value

```
resource "aws_instance" "dev" {

  ami           = "ami-0ca285d4c2cda3300"
  instance_type = var.instanceType
  count         = var.istest ? 1 : 0
}

resource "aws_instance" "prod" {

  ami           = "ami-0ca285d4c2cda3300"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  count         = var.istest ? 0 : 1
}
```

This way if the istest var is `true` it will deploy the `dev` instance.

And if it is `false` it will create the `prod` instance

Try

```
terraform plan -var="istest=false"
```

---

**UPDATE**

The core issue seems to be that terraform performs type conversions

Quoting from: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/type-constraints#conversion-of-primitive-types

> The Terraform language will `automatically convert number and bool`
> `values to string values when needed`, and vice-versa as long as the
> string contains a valid representation of a number or boolean value.
>
> `true converts to "true", and vice-versa false converts to "false"`

As a result you should explicitly set the `type` of the variable

In your `variables.tf` file

```
variable "istest" {
  default = true
  type    = bool
}
```

Then it should work as expected

```
terraform plan -var="istest=false"
```

Comment: altought your answer is correct (and upvoted) it does not explain why checking against the literal true or false value would be a problem.... I suspect the missing type constraints in variables.tf

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: @fun_times Updated answer with root cause explanation, thanks again

Comment: This works, so if i use type= bool, then var.istest == false ? 1 : 0 works or without type=bool var.istest ? 0 : 1 works

Comment: @JatinMehrotra If you go with the second approach, then all you need to add is type = bool

Comment: @JatinMehrotra If you use the first approach you need to avoid using the literal true, in your conditional logic